# Best way to determine if simple or extended MAPI was loaded

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

How can I simply determine if simple or extended MAPI is loaded.
Because I want to diable my add in wenn simple MAPI is loaded.
I'm working with Add-In Express and Redemption.dll.

Comment: Can you clarify? SMAPI and Extended MAPI are libraries that need to be referenced to write code against, so they aren't "loaded" in your add-in unless you are explicitly referencing any objects in those APIs  Extended MAPI requires C++ to work with, and SMAPI is irrelevant to use in an Add-in Express project.

Comment: When you use the right mouse button to send a file via email from Windows, the simple mapi is used. When the user wants to use my add in, I want to prompt a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Windows "Send To" command actually integrates with SendMail.dll.  AFAIK you can't intercept these calls to do something custom, but you can add your own shortcuts in the context menu:

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/create-a-custom-send-to-shortcut/

Comment: All I want is to change the behavior of my addon if the simple mapi is used. if(simplemapi) else. I only have to identify which mapi is used.

Comment: The problem with emails created using SendMail is that the Application.NewInspector event doesn't get thrown. There is NO event that fires when these emails are created. SendMail breaks a lot of things.

Comment: Whats the best way to detect if SendMail is used?

Comment: As I explained already, you cannot. You have to add your own shortcut to the right-click menu that runs your own custom application if you want to intercept it.

Comment: This do not solve my problem. My plugin can not work with simple MAPI, therefore it must be disabled. If I implement my own shortcut, the plugin is loaded anyway when the user is using the SendMail. How do other add in developer solve this problem when their add in can only work with extended MAPI? Thanks

Comment: If you implement your own shortcut you still must implement the sending logic - it won't be using SendMail. So the shortcut can point to your own .dll or .exe and your code can use the Outlook Object Model to create and display the message, and the NewInspector event will fire and your add-in will work normally. If you want to disable your add-in when the default SendMail component is used with the default Send To command, then you can't unfortunately. You could delete the Send To shortcut and force users to use your own custom shortcut and sending application.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my solution below!?

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution? Could this leading to problems?

```
Outlook.Application outlookApp = null;
Outlook.Explorer outExp = null;

try
{
    outlookApp = (Outlook.Application)AddinModule.CurrentInstance.OutlookApp;
    outExp = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer() as Outlook.Explorer;

    if (outExp != null)
    {
       // extended stuff
    } else {
       // simple stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very basic code that doesn't really do anything so I'm not sure how it applies to this scenario. There is another possibility though: use a timer in a class somewhere that constantly polls Inspectors.Count and compare it with another counter that increments when NewInspector fires. When the timer fires it can compare the two counts and when they differ you'll know that a new window was created from SendMail.

Comment: For sure this is simple and solves my problem. When only an inspector is open (SendMail) its the simple mapi and I disable my add in. When also an explorer is open, extended mapi is active.